# How to get count of similar numbers in array

Tags: c, arrays

Let's imagine that we have a C without any libraries (embeded world). I would like to know some good implementation to get count of majority numbers in array which are close to each other around defined offset.
Example (offset +/- 10):

```
array(1, 5, 9, 50, 2, 54, 3, 1, 58, 59, 56, 54, 48, 2), result 7
array(1, 5, 4, 8, 60, 500, 200, 7, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4), result 10
```

Comment: Is this homework ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You should probably start by sorting the array.

Comment: Is worst case O(n^2) ok? Then it´s somewhat trivial...

Comment: Sorting is not necessary. worst case will be O(n^2) anyway as Devian said

Comment: 1) Sort array 2) March a pointer from least to greatest.  March another pointer such that `*p2 - *p1 <= (10 - -10 or 20)`.  The difference in pointers `(p2 - p1)` is the _count_.  3) Return the highest _count_.  O(n*ln2(n))

Comment: as a perl one liner ``perl -e 'for $x(@ARGV){ push @b, scalar(grep($x <$_+10 && $x >$_-10, @ARGV))} print ((sort { $b <=> $a} @b)[0]);' 1 5 9 50 2 54 3 1 58 59 56 54 48 2``

Comment: No, really it is not a homework. I need to collect data from ultrasonic sensor and I need to do some small filtering. It is a little bit more complex, I tried avarage or mooving avarage also some kind of signal filtering but because of wrong mechanical design I need to found out my own solution how to drop wrong values.

Comment: Maybe start with sorting is not that bad. After it I just have to find the stream of numbers which are in the range and offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take one number at a time and check how many numbers that are in its "range of x".

Iterate the array and check each number with:

```
For (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    int sum = 0
    int result = CheckNumbersInRange(i, array, range)
    if (result > sum)
        sum = result;
}
```

// here you now have the number you want.

Now you just need to make a function that checks how many numbers are in the range of array[i].
There you could iterate the whole array again and compare each elementm and count it up every time you satisfy the condition. At the end return the number of elements in range.

```
int CheckNumbersInRange(int i, int array[], int range){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
        if (array[i] < (array[j] + range) && array[i] > (array[j] - range))
            sum++;
    }
    return (sum -1); // because the array[i] will count up itself.
}
```

Comment: So simple and I was so blind, thank you. I do not need so much items in array (maybe around 10) so there is no reason for me to sort array.

Answer (score 0):

Sort array
For each element in the array:
Note the max_index at which `Num[max] - Num[i] <= (10 - -10 + or 20)`.
The difference in indexes is the count.
Return the highest count.

O(n*ln2(n))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  int ia = *((int*) a);
  int ib = *((int*) b);
  return (ia>ib) - (ia<ib);
}

size_t LongRun(int *Num, size_t n, int range) {
  // This is a placeholder for a user sort().  OP does not want to use libraries
  qsort(Num, n, sizeof *Num, fcmp);  

  size_t lo_i;
  size_t hi_i = 0;
  size_t LongestRun = 0;
  for (lo_i = 0; lo_i<n; lo_i++) {
    while (hi_i < n && Num[hi_i] - Num[lo_i] <= range) hi_i++;
    if (hi_i - lo_i >  LongestRun) LongestRun = hi_i - lo_i;
  }
  return LongestRun;
}

void Doit(int *Num, size_t n) {
  size_t i;
  fputs("(", stdout);
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf(" %d,", Num[i]);
  size_t lr = LongRun(Num, n, 10 - -10);
  fputs(")\n", stdout);
  fputs("(", stdout);
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf(" %d,", Num[i]);
  fputs(")", stdout);
  printf(": %zu\n", lr);
}

int main(void) {
  int a1[] = {1, 5, 9, 50, 2, 54, 3, 1, 58, 59, 56, 54, 48, 2};
  Doit(a1, sizeof a1 / sizeof a1[0]);
  int a2[] = {1, 5, 4, 8, 60, 500, 200, 7, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4};
  Doit(a2, sizeof a2 / sizeof a2[0]);
  return 0;
  }

( 1, 5, 9, 50, 2, 54, 3, 1, 58, 59, 56, 54, 48, 2,)  
( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 48, 50, 54, 54, 56, 58, 59,): 7

( 1, 5, 4, 8, 60, 500, 200, 7, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4,)
( 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 60, 200, 500,): 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort the array, and use a queue to count the number of close elements.

Here is the code (in C++ and not in C) demonstrating the algorithm (assuming `v` is sorted)  :

```
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
int foo(vector<int> v, int offset)
{
    queue<int> q;
    int max = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        q.push(v[i]);
        if (v[i] - q.front() <= offset)
        {
            if (q.size() > max)
            {
                max = q.size();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (!q.empty() && (v[i] - q.front() > offset))
            {
                q.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: -1 This is tagged C.

Comment: Nice but no way implement this in C inside the embeded system.